# AspectJ weaving exception (org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Whilst processing type..) while running tests on Jenkins

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng, aspectj, allure

Trying to run few tests (Using Testng:7.1.0, Oracle JDK:1.8, Spring Boot:2.2.7, Allure:2.13, Aspectjweaver:1.9.5) on Jenkins CI but getting the following error (this issue is not occurring on my local system and everything works fine):

```
org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: Whilst processing type 'Lcom/compuware/apm/agent/introspection/uem/impl/AgentInjectingUemResponseHook$1;' - cannot cast the outer type to a reference type.  Signature=Lcom/compuware/apm/agent/introspection/uem/impl/AgentInjectingUemResponseHook; toString()=com.compuware.apm.agent.introspection.uem.impl.AgentInjectingUemResponseHook class=AgentInjectingUemResponseHook
when processing type mungers 
when weaving 

    at org.aspectj.weaver.AbstractReferenceTypeDelegate.getFormalTypeParametersFromOuterClass(AbstractReferenceTypeDelegate.java:115)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:775)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getSuperclass(BcelObjectType.java:231)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getSuperclass(ReferenceType.java:993)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveParentsFor(BcelWeaver.java:1313)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1126)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:551)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:116)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.resolve(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter.isPresent(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition$ClassNameFilter$2.matches(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcome(OnClassCondition.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcome(OnClassCondition.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.getOutcomes(OnClassCondition.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition$StandardOutcomesResolver.resolveOutcomes(OnClassCondition.java:190)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition.resolveOutcomesThreaded(OnClassCondition.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition.getOutcomes(OnClassCondition.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.FilteringSpringBootCondition.match(FilteringSpringBootCondition.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.filter(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:396)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
```

The ajcore text dump takes around 5 minutes to be ready and haven't been able to stop that. I have tried setting system property as `org.aspectj.weaver.Dump.condition=abort` and `org.aspectj.weaver.Dump.exception=false` to no avail.

Also, can't find anything useful in the dump:

```
---- AspectJ Properties ---
AspectJ Compiler 1.9.5 built on Thursday Nov 28, 2019 at 11:28:53 PST
---- Dump Properties ---
Dump file: ajcore.20200716.110035.093.txt
Dump reason: org.aspectj.weaver.BCException
Dump on exception: true
Dump at exit condition: abort
---- Exception Information ---
---- System Properties ---
//////////////////////////
---- Command Line ---
Empty
---- Full Classpath ---
Empty
---- Compiler Messages ---
Empty
```

I have also tried using older versions of aspectjweaver but no luck.

Any clue what might be wrong here?

Comment: This sounds tricky, but interesting. Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as minimal as possible, reproducing the problem (on your Jenkins), then push it to GitHub and quote the relevant parts here. This could be a case for the AspectJ mailing list and maybe for Bugzilla, but there you would need a reproducer to work with as well. So let's clarify here first. This might be an AspectJ weaver bug or limitation, but similar errors also occur if there is a faulty aspect leading to partial compilation of target files. Let's find out inspecting the MCVE.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex, I will give it a try but not sure if I'll succeed :)
Any idea how the processing for ajcore can be disabled?

Comment: I didn't try, but you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708104/1082681). I will get active here again when I see the MCVE.

Comment: That setting did not work, already tried. Anyway thanks for help @kriegaex. This is not a blocker issue for me because execution continues post the aspectj exception. Also, if I can get an MCVE will edit my post.

Comment: I think you should take it more seriously. The error message suggests that something might be wrong with your aspect. It might not do what you expect it to, maybe in a subtle way. Bugs like those can be a bitch, especially when forgotten and then needing debugging in the future when they cause more trouble unexpectedly, out of today's context. But it is not my application, so I am relaxed. :-)